# Random Module AttributeError , 'random' has no attribute 'randint'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

```
import random
a = random.randint(5, 10)
print(a)
```

This code won't execute in VSCode, but works just fine in powershell.
Here is the error I have been getting in VSCode

[image]

Edit: The file was named random.py, and thus caused the error.

Comment: Do you have a file in the same folder called `random.py`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rename your file from `random.py` to something else. Python is getting confused because the file name shadows the `random` module.

BTW, this is what the circular import warning is about. You are importing `random`, which is the file name. So, it imports the file you wrote. Whenever it imports the file, `import random` is executed, which imports the file you wrote...